# Discounting losses in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm writing my master thesis on the costs of occupational injuries. As a part of the thesis I have estimated the expected wage loss for each person for every year for four years after the injure. I would like to discount the estimated losses to a specific base year (2009) in SAS.

For the year 2009 the discounted loss is just equal the estimated loss. For 2010 and on the discounted loss can be calculated with the netpv function:

```
    IF year=2009 then discount_loss=wage;
    IF year=2010 then discount_loss=netpv(0.1,1,0,wage);
    IF year=2011 then discount_loss=netpv(0.1,1,0,0,wage);
```

And so forth. But starting from 2014 I would like to use the estimated wage loss for 2014 as the expected loss onward - so for instance if the estimated loss is 100$ that would represent the yearly loss until retirement. Since each person  don't have the same age there would be too many ways just to hard code, so I'm looking for a better way. There are approximately 200.000 persons in my data set with different estimated losses for each year.

The format of the (fictional) data looks like this:

```
   id  age  year  age_retirement  wage_loss rate discount_loss 
   1   35   2009      65            -100     0.1   -100
   1   36   2010      65            -100     0.1   -90,91
   1   37   2011      65            -100     0.1   -82,64
   1   38   2012      65            -100     0.1   -75,13
   1   39   2013      65            -100     0.1   -68,30
   1   40   2014      65            -100     0.1
```

The column discount_loss is the net present value of the loss i 2009. Calculated as above. 
I would like the loss in 2014 to represent the sum of losses for the rest of the period (until age_retirement) on the labor market. That would be -100$ discounted for 2009 starting from 2014 until 2014+(65-40).

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't sound like what you want to do should be very difficult.  However, I'm not exactly sure what you want calculated.  Without using the netpv function could you provide 1 concrete example of what you are looking for? show both your input data and output data.

Comment: I apologize for not being crystal clear on this one. In the provided dataset the person has 25 years until retirement (65-40) in 2014. If I want to calculate the net present value I would have to write netpv(0.1,1,0,0,0,0,0,wage_loss,wage_loss,wage_loss…). I want to use a more efficient way, since I have a lot of individuals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `FINANCE` function for `PV`, Present Value. 
In your situation above, you're looking for the value of 100 for 25 years of payments (65-40)=25. I'll leave the calculation of the number of years up to you.

```
FINANCE('PV', rate, nper, payment, <fv>, <type>);
```

In your case, Future Value is 0 and the type=1 as you assume payment at the beginning of the year. 
The formula below calculates the present value of a series of 100 payments over 25 years with a 10% interest rate and paid at the beginning of the period.

```
value=FINANCE('PV', 0.1, 25, -100, 0, 1);
```

> Value =  998.47440201

Reference is here:
https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67960/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1cnn1jwdmhce0n1obxmu4iq26ge.htm

Comment: Sorry, I'm 4 hours of sleep is not sufficient.

Comment: Nope its not...I rarely get that much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for speed why not first calculate an array that contains the PV of $1 for for i years where i goes from 1 to n.  Then just select the element you need and multiply.  This could all be done in a data step.